# cron expression failing on aws lambda

Tags: cron, aws-lambda

I want this endpoint to be hit every ten minutes apart from on sunday

I've tried

```
cron(5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * 1-6 *)
```

and

```
cron(0/10 * * * 1-6 *)
```

`cron(5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * ? *)` works, but WITH the days specified, either in this format or MON-SAT format, does not work and throws my serverless deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will work for you:

```
cron(5/10 * ? * Mon-Sat *)
```

The reason for the `?` in the `Day-of-Month` field is because:

> You can't specify the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields in the same cron expression. If you specify a value (or a *) in one of the fields, you must use a ? (question mark) in the other.

In addition to run it "on the fives" use `5/10` because:

> The / (forward slash) wildcard specifies increments. In the Minutes field, you could enter 1/10 to specify every tenth minute, starting from the first minute of the hour (for example, the 11th, 21st, and 31st minute, and so on).
>   **References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

Answer (score 2):

> every 10 min Mon-Sat

```
cron(0/10 * ? * MON-SAT *)
```

reference Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html